# JPA and eclipselink - Overriding FetchType.Eager

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have a class where a few members have annotation:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

In the specific part of my program, these load far too many data. Unfortunately, I can't change these annotations as this will influence performance of other parts of this program.  Is there a way in eclipselink to change this to LAZY for 1 specific JPQL query?

To phrase this an other way, you can change LAZY to EAGER by using a fetch join. I'm hoping for something which changes EAGER to LAZY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. My rule of thumb is : make everything LAZY, and use custom queries if you want eager fetching.

The best you can do is to load tuples (and populate DTOs) instead of loading entities.

Comment: I think I'll just live with the horrible performance until we can do a more major overhaul.

Answer (score 0):

I know that since eclipselink 2.3 you can extend your entities at runtime, maybe check that? 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Extensibility

Comment: This is scary stuff, maintenance-wise ;-) Even so, thanks for letting me know about this corener of eclipselink. One day it will be handy!